How can I get my form submissions to create new documents in a collection? Firebase Console and Flutterflow not working
I am desperately looking for advise on how to solve an issue with creating collections and documents.

I have a profile page with a submit button. However when I go in test mode as an authenticated user I am unable to see the data stored in Firebase Console or in Flutterflow.

The fields are: first_name, last_name, age, bio.
I created the collection in Flutterflow and have also tried creating it manually in Firebase Console.
Despite the collection existing in either or both places, the document is not created.
My action flow is:
Select Firestore > Create Document.
Collection: Set to profiles.
Document ID: empty
firstName: Click Set from Variable, select Widget State, choose firstName.
lastName: Click Set from Variable, select Widget State, choose lastName.
age: Click Set from Variable, select Widget State, choose age.
bio: Click Set from Variable, select Widget State, choose bio.
Rules:
`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /profiles/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}`


I've exhausted all options available to me and hoping someone has encountered this issue. Better yet, the solution is simple and user error.
Thanks so much!
I tried:

creating the collection and a test document manually in Firebase Console
creating the collection in Flutterflow (unable to add a document after pressing add document)
running the app in test mode and submitting the form (expecting to see a document in Firebase Console

